# Using pointers to members and macros

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm having problems with the following code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<utility>

#define Row *prow
#define Col *pcol

typedef unsigned int uint;
typedef std::pair<uint, uint> Node;

uint Node::Row = &Node::first;
uint Node::Col = &Node::second;

int main()
{
    Node node(1,2);
    std::cout << node.*prow << node.*pcol << '\n';    // OK
    std::cout << node.Row << node.Col << '\n';        // doesn't compile
}
```

The idea was to use std::pair but replace `first` and `second` with other names, in that case `Row` and `Col`. However, the last line doesn't compile even though it should be exactly the same as the line before it. I'd really appreciate if someone could explain me why it happens. I'm using VS2015.

Edit: compiler error `C2059 syntax error:'*'`

Comment: What's the compile error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.*` is a single token. Your macro is generating two adjacent tokens, `.` and `*`, which is not the same thing. (Or at least it might do. Almost certainly you're invoking undefined behaviour.)

There's probably a solution involving token pasting, but you'd do yourself a big favour (and make Bjarne happy) by just not using macros in C++.

Comment: +1. Tokens composition is a very common cause of many errors in C++, especially in code involving macros. -1 for last sentence, however. Although constructs presented by OP belong to the path of the dark side, macros are very powerful and can be very useful. I doubt, that Bjarne would be happy if macros were cut off from C++.

Comment: These examples shows *wrong* usage of macros - they are not a replacement for simple functions (`inline`) or compile-time constants (`enum`). That's exactly what I said - they can be easily used in wrong way. Now consider complex constants definitions, that require a compile-time expression (`constexpr` is a C++ 11 feature, so it may not be an option) or expanding statements with current source location attached (`__FILE__`/`__FUNCTION__`), which is used by many debug/exception layers - how would you do that without macros and with the same (i.e. none) run-time overhead? Good luck with that.